# Do conditional comments only work for stylesheets?

Tags: php, javascript, html, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

Do conditional comments only work for CSS styles and stylesheet links, or can they be applied to all HTML/JS. I'm asking because I'd like to display a specific message if the user is using a browser in which some functionality is known not to work/function as well as it could in others?

If not, is there anyway, via PHP + regex to get the exact browser that the user is using, as `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` seems to return a string containing several user agent names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean stuff like:

```
<!--[if lte IE 6]> ... <![endif]-->
```

yes, you can use this in HTML too (eg. it is often used to conditionally add some extra CSS for IE6 fixes).

But I wouldn't rely on this in order to, let's say, tell the user to upgrade the outdated browser. Instead, I would do that on the server-side by checking the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.

The browser recognition isn't straight-forward since browsers tend to format the user-agent as they like; there are many libraries that use comparisons lists etc. in order to try figure out which actually is the browser/version/os by parsing the user-agent string.

Comment: I just took a look at the php function `get_browser()` which seems promising, but the comments below speak as though it's rather faulty. Have you any experience using it, and if not, do you have any specific lists or libraries for user agent matching that you could recommend?. All I really want to do is display a warning to users who download my paid application, that they'd be better off using it in Chrome or Firefox rather than IE.

Comment: http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php/  you could use this guy and pass a different class in for each, changing your message with generated content and pseudo selectors

Answer (score 0):

conditional comments "work" in markup, you can wrap them around CSS, HTML and JavaScript. Just wrap whatever for non IE with [if !IE]